# Clearcase: Prevent developers from modifying configspec

Tags: version-control, clearcase

I work as a repo manager for an organization with large teams of developers. Despite our communication efforts, standards definition and awarness raising, we still get developers modifying their configspecs while developing, instead of simply doing a findmerge to retrieve latest developments.

How do you usually deal with such issues? Is there a way to prevent users (coders) from modifying the configspec, once the view is created?

Comment: Meaning all due respect, I'd be considering moving away from Clearcase to something easier to administer such as Mercurial or Git.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avoiding config spec modification is part of the main goals behind the UCM ([Unified Change Management](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_Rational_ClearCase_UCM)) methodology.

But if you are stuck with "base" ClearCase (no UCM), one potential workaround is to promote common config spec *included* within the user config spec.
But that doesn't prevent changes.

I have also seen some admins playing around with ACL rights on the `config_spec` file within a view storage (in order to make it non-modifiable by any `cleartool setcs`). But I haven't tested that method personally.